# Jquery sortable table: update method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm working on a sortable table with Jquery. I have to say I'm quite a newbie with Jquery. Basically, I can make the rows sortable and use a placeholder:

```
<tbody id="table-list">
        <tr class="raw" id="raw-{$sottoGirone->id}">
            <!-- some ths -->
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
    $('tbody').sortable({
      placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
    });
    $( 'tbody' ).disableSelection();
</script>
```

but I also need to do stuff whenever an item is moved. So I tried to follow some tutorials and put:

```
$('tbody').sortable({
    update: function(event, ui) {
                   alert();
                }
});
```

but that way, the rows are not sortable anymore.
I also found that

```
$( 'tbody' ).on( "update", function( event, ui ) {alert();} );
```

should work, but it's doing nothing instead.

How can I solve this?

Comment: The full event name is `sortupdate`, usage is `$('tbody').on('sortupdate', ...` It's a bit unclear what the problem is. Could you make a [mcve]?

Comment: I followed this tutorial: [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jqueryui/jqueryui_sortable.htm)

which says the event is "update". by the way what you suggested worked. I should now into the arguments passed to the callback hoping they're the same as the ones I found for "update"

Comment: When a jQueryUI widget invokes an event, it prefixes it with the widget name (thus, `sort` + `update`) The [widget factory doc page](http://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.widget/) goes in more detail